# I upgraded Debian 10 to Debian 11, then Debian 12. Why does previously used commands now say out of memory?

Tags: debian, rsync, du, outofmemoryerror

I upgraded two low end vps systems only used for mail and dns from Debian 10 to Debian 11 then to Debian 12. No issues during either upgrade for either system. I have a cron that rsync's the vmail folder from one server to the other in case I need a quick hot standby. After the upgrade the same rysnc command spams

```
rsync: [sender] readlink_stat("/home/vmail/folder/filename) failed: Cannot allocate memory (12)
```

and then just exits. This had been working for months before this upgrade.

rsync command:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -a -e "ssh -p9999" /home/vmail/ destserver:/home/vmail/
```

Both servers have version:

```
rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31
```

Source server memory specs

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            2560         352        1184           3        1026        2207
Swap:            256           1         254
```

Dest server memory specs

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            1024          73         479           0         471         950
Swap:            256          81         174
```

The same thing happens when doing a du of the vmail folder, on either server.

Comment: What size is file `/home/vmail/folder/filename`?

Comment: Are all packages updated? try `apt full-upgrade`

Comment: All packages are upgraded. I did the full-upgrade as part of the process. Individual mail files are small, a few k each mostly. There are roughly 143k files/folders total.  In getting the total size for this reply du of the /home/vmail folder also reports "Cannot allocate memory".